# Why does my Base64 encoded hash only contain 28 characters?

Tags: c#, base64, encode, sha

The [inverse question exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075378/why-does-my-base64-encoded-sha-1-hash-contain-56-chars) with no answer and a comment that I don't understand.

I am attempting to create a Base64 encoded [HMAC-SHA1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1(v=vs.110).aspx) signature for a pseudo OAuth authentication header for an API. I found a support document (requires authenticated access) that takes you through the evolution of creating the signature. I'm able to create the same data up until the final step which is to Base64 encode the hash.

The support document states that the HMAC-SHA1 signature is:

```
cb5acd2d3ef689a8fbec4d06c576371834689673
```

And I get:

```
CB5ACD2D3EF689A8FBEC4D06C576371834689673
```

The support document then states

> From the hex result string in step 3, encode the value using Base64

and provides the following Base64 encoded result (58 characters):

```
Y2I1YWNkMmQzZWY2ODlhOGZiZWM0ZDA2YzU3NjM3MTgzNDY4OTY3Mw==
```

When I use `Convert.ToBase64String()` to convert my signature I get (28 characters):

```
y1rNLT72iaj77E0GxXY3GDRolnM=
```

I'm stumped, I don't know if the support document is incorrect or if I'm doing something wrong. The fact that I'm generating a string that is 28 characters and the example is 56 is too interesting to ignore.

The comment in the [aforementioned semi-duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075378/why-does-my-base64-encoded-sha-1-hash-contain-56-chars) also stumps me. I don't see how the string "MDY" translates to any ascii or unicode digits that make sense to me - I don't understand how the comment author came to that conclusion.

> The hex value is being encoded as text ("062..." == 0x30, 0x36, 0x32,
>   ...) rather than as the large number it represents.

Comment: The longer base64 string is the base64 encoding of the string `"cb5acd2...` while the shorter is the base64 encoding of the byte array `new byte[] {0xcb, 0x5a, 0xcd...`.

Answer (score 4):

Your signature is a 20 byte (160 bit) long byte array.
So it's basically a very long number.

When you show it, you are converting it into a hex string, so each byte is shown as 2 chars, so you get a 40 chars long string.

Base64 encoding gives you 4 chars every 3 bytes of payload to encode.

If you encode in base64 20 bytes of binary data you get 26.6 bytes, rounded up to 28 (you round up every 4 bytes).
If you encode your 40 characters long string (320 bits), you get 53,3 characters, again rounded up to 56.

I suppose you're doing the latter, and encoding a string instead of a byte[].

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the same problem here. You have to convert sha1sum result to a Hex format. For example, when your sha1sum result is `dfe5ec35f9c9f144d3814821a558bcfa23ab1a58`, the console outputs it in string format.

You may use ***UltraEdit*** or another text editor, edit it as hex.

[image]

And then save it as a file.
The right answer `3+XsNfnJ8UTTgUghpVi8+iOrGlg=` comes out after you base64 encode the file.

Have a try. Hope it helps.

Comment: That's right, but I didn't have enough reputation to comment to Mr A Chiesa's answer then~~